# Why does this scope return the wrong objects for an enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

On my `Post.rb` model, I have this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  enum is_published: [ :no, :yes ]

  scope :published, -> { where( is_published: "yes") }
  scope :unpublished, -> { where( is_published: "no") }
end
```

But when I try to execute this in my console, it gives me faulty results:

```
 > Post.published.count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."is_published" = 0
 => 5 
 > Post.published
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."is_published" = 0
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 20, title: "Chang calls for immediate removal of Davies, JUTC ...", photo: nil, body: "Opposition spokesperson on Transport, Horace Chang...", created_at: "2014-08-30 11:07:05", updated_at: "2014-08-30 20:03:56", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: "Davies-Must-Go.pdf", status: 0, slug: "chang-calls-for-immediate-removal-of-davies-jutc-m...", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>, #<Post id: 21, title: "PNP Chairman expresses shock, grief at Clarke’s pa...", photo: nil, body: "Chairman of the People’s National Party (PNP), the...", created_at: "2014-08-30 13:22:05", updated_at: "2014-08-30 20:03:56", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: 1, slug: "pnp-chairman-expresses-shock-grief-at-clarke-s-pas...", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>, #<Post id: 22, title: "ALGAJ Pays Tribute to the Honourable Roger Clarke", photo: nil, body: "The Association of Local Government Authorities of...", created_at: "2014-08-30 16:19:12", updated_at: "2014-08-30 20:03:56", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: 2, slug: "algaj-pays-tribute-to-the-honourable-roger-clarke", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>, #<Post id: 26, title: "PNPYO saddened at passing of Roger Clarke", photo: nil, body: "The People’s National Youth Organisation (PNPYO), ...", created_at: "2014-08-30 19:50:47", updated_at: "2014-08-30 19:50:47", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: 1, slug: "pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>, #<Post id: 25, title: "10PP 1 on 2", photo: "1-on-1-Icon.jpg", body: "10PP gives you a lot of one on one attention that ...", created_at: "2014-08-30 17:35:17", updated_at: "2014-08-30 20:09:05", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: 0, slug: "10pp-1-on-2", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>]> 
 > Post.published.first.is_published
  Post Load (3.6ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."is_published" = 0  ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => "no"
```

As you can see, the first object in the AR relation returned from `Post.published` actually has the value of `"no"`.

Likewise, if I did `Post.unpublished` I would get the same data set:

```
 > Post.unpublished.count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."is_published" = 0
 => 5 
 > Post.unpublished
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."is_published" = 0
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 20, title: "Chang calls for immediate removal of Davies, JUTC ...", photo: nil, body: "Opposition spokesperson on Transport, Horace Chang...", created_at: "2014-08-30 11:07:05", updated_at: "2014-08-30 20:03:56", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: "Davies-Must-Go.pdf", status: 0, slug: "chang-calls-for-immediate-removal-of-davies-jutc-m...", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>, #<Post id: 21, title: "PNP Chairman expresses shock, grief at Clarke’s pa...", photo: nil, body: "Chairman of the People’s National Party (PNP), the...", created_at: "2014-08-30 13:22:05", updated_at: "2014-08-30 20:03:56", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: 1, slug: "pnp-chairman-expresses-shock-grief-at-clarke-s-pas...", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>, #<Post id: 22, title: "ALGAJ Pays Tribute to the Honourable Roger Clarke", photo: nil, body: "The Association of Local Government Authorities of...", created_at: "2014-08-30 16:19:12", updated_at: "2014-08-30 20:03:56", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: 2, slug: "algaj-pays-tribute-to-the-honourable-roger-clarke", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>, #<Post id: 26, title: "PNPYO saddened at passing of Roger Clarke", photo: nil, body: "The People’s National Youth Organisation (PNPYO), ...", created_at: "2014-08-30 19:50:47", updated_at: "2014-08-30 19:50:47", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: 1, slug: "pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>, #<Post id: 25, title: "10PP 1 on 2", photo: "1-on-1-Icon.jpg", body: "10PP gives you a lot of one on one attention that ...", created_at: "2014-08-30 17:35:17", updated_at: "2014-08-30 20:09:05", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: 0, slug: "10pp-1-on-2", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false>]> 
 > Post.unpublished.first
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."is_published" = 0  ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Post id: 20, title: "Chang calls for immediate removal of Davies, JUTC ...", photo: nil, body: "Opposition spokesperson on Transport, Horace Chang...", created_at: "2014-08-30 11:07:05", updated_at: "2014-08-30 20:03:56", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: "Davies-Must-Go.pdf", status: 0, slug: "chang-calls-for-immediate-removal-of-davies-jutc-m...", is_published: 0, has_eyewitness: false> 
 > Post.unpublished.first.is_published
  Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."is_published" = 0  ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => "no"
```

What is also interesting is that the 1 record in my `Post` table that does have `is_published: "yes"` is never returned.

As can be seen here:

```
 > p = Post.first
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Post id: 1, title: "Fire at Bible College in Christian", photo: nil, body: "A massive fire is now raging at the Bible College ...", created_at: "2014-08-28 08:06:19", updated_at: "2014-09-18 20:56:32", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: 0, slug: "fire-at-bible-college-in-christian", is_published: 1, has_eyewitness: true> 
 > p.is_published
 => "yes"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; `is_published: [:yes, :no]` is not a suitable use of `enum`.

---

There's a lot wrong with that enum, and with the scopes that use it.

First, you can't use `where` that way. You're sidestepping the `enum` entirely and just querying against the column. Rails converts your query value to an integer since you're querying against an integer column. Both `"yes"` and `"no"` convert to integer `0`, so those scopes cannot work. If you're going to use `where`, you need to manually produce the correct integer value. It looks like this for your model:

```
Post.where(is_published: Post.is_publisheds['yes'])
```

Second, note the very awkward pluralization of `is_publisheds`; this is a hint that you're using a bad name for your enum.

Thirdly, you're manually making redundant scopes. Rails already gives you scopes for each of the values in your `enum`, but you've chosen *really* bad names. Your model now has `yes` and `no` scopes! You can use `Post.yes` and `Post.no` to get your published/unpublished records, but this is obviously pretty wrong.

This all stems from the fact that you've basically enumerated a *boolean*. That misses the point completely. If you're really just after a boolean, `enum` is not suitable, and you shouldn't use it. Just use a boolean column, and write a pair of sane scopes with `where(is_published: true)` and `where(is_published: false)`.

If you want to use an enum, instead of using `is_published`, use `enum status: [:published, :unpublished]`, or even `enum publication_status: [:published, :unpublished]`. That is all you need. Rails will look at the enumeration values, and generate the two scopes you're after for you, with no additional work on your part.

The entire class looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  enum status: [ :published, :unpublished ]
  # No need for scopes, enum gives you published/unpublished scopes already
end
```

Comment: Thanks for not just correcting me, but also explaining. This is something that I did struggle with, so it is no surprise that I used it incorrectly. It did feel wrong while I was doing it, and your suggestion makes a ton of sense. Thanks much! So with that `enum status`, I would be able to simply do `Post.published?` right? Also `Post.where(:published)` to get all the posts that have been published?

Answer (score 1):

Checking [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) documentation shows the following syntax for your scopes:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  enum is_published: [ :no, :yes ]

  scope :published, -> { where( is_published: Post.is_publisheds[:yes] ) }
  scope :unpublished, -> { where( is_published: Post.is_publisheds[:no]) }
end
```

Your query shows that you're getting `0` for "yes" which does not look correct.  With this suggested change, you should get correct enum value for `yes` and `no`.  Also on a side note the documentation states:

> Where conditions on an enum attribute must use the ordinal value of an
>   enum.

Comment: `is_published[:yes]` would be an error; it's `is_publisheds`, the pluralized version of the column name.